# API App in Azure does not reflect changes after continuous integration deployments

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have setup continuous deployment of a standard web api project to an API App on Azure. The new version is deployed to the staging slot and then swapped with production at the end of the release task. I can see that (by going to App Service Editor in azure portal) the dll file versions reflect the latest changes. But when I access the APIs (from a webapp or postman) on this Azure app the result does not reflect the published changes. The only way I can force the new changes is either restarting the API app or stopping and starting the app service.

Am I missing anything in using continuous integration with API app on Azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this by adding a new task available in VSO release which restarts the staging slot before swapping with production. This makes sure that the new changes are part of the IIS process.